# winapi openfiledialog c++

Tags: c++, winapi, openfiledialog

I use mingw, c++
I would like to open multiple files, something like this:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFilter = "TXT\0"
        "*.txt\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;
ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
```

But how can I get the filenameS? If I check the szFileName variable, it only contains the folder name.

Comment: FWIW, the first three lines of the code above can be written simply as `OPENFILENAME ofn = {sizeof(ofn)};`

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site -> Too localized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the user selects more than one file, the **`lpstrFile`** buffer returns the path to the current directory followed by the file names of the selected files. The **`nFileOffset`** member is the offset, in bytes or characters, to the first file name
>
> the directory and file name strings are NULL separated, with an extra NULL character after the last file name.

From your question:

> If I check the szFileName variable, it only contains the folder name.

Keep checking one character past the terminating `'\0'`.

Each time the following character *isn't* another `'\0'`, that's the start of a new filename.

Comment: +1 @Carl You'll be wanting a much bigger buffer than the 260 char at present.